# How to deploy maven library dependency in Gitlab?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I want to deploy a Maven Dependency package (Spring Boot Library Project) in GitLab, so that I could use this library as a dependency in other projects.

Now I went through the Gitlab Package docs and below are the changes I made as per docs.

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.one</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>${env.CI_COMMIT_TAG}</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>Common Library</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${env.CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${env.CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${env.CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also created `ci_settings.xml` file

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Job-Token</name>
                        <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

For CI/CD , added `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

deploy-job:      
  stage: deploy  
  environment: production
  script:
    - mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Now after creating a new tag `0.0.1` in Gitlab Repository, the pipeline is initiated and package deployed.

The problem is when adding the package dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.one</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in another project within same group, I get below error

```
com.example.one:common:jar:0.0.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous
 attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until
 the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I also tried adding `<repositories>` tag in target project, but then I get different error

```
com.example.one:common:jar:0.0.1 was not found in https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/maven
 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
 reattempted until the update interval of gitlab-maven has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get a `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS` and `Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab...` ? If no, we should work on. If so: ;(;( ... : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36076   ...`mvn install`!? (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/)

Comment: yes, I did get [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS and Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab...

Comment: @xerx593 , do you have any other solution ?

Comment: I do not get the `Uploading...` log after `BUILD SUCESS`, but you got past that point.  I don't get an error or anything, it is almost as if it does not even try.  Did you run into any problems with that part, or did it work right away for you?  Getting ready to post a new question, but your question is close to what I need, so starting here.

Comment: Never mind, I did not have things setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Since the package is in a **private repository** , I was not authenticating the `gitlab-maven` dependency call.

I added the `servers` with `deploy-token` of `gitlab` in target project `maven` `settings.xml`